# Flask + Stripe - how can I prevent people from accessing my successful checkout page without making a payment?

Tags: flask, stripe-payments

Basically I understand how to integrate Stripe payment into Flask, I'm using the official website (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=elements) as a guide. In the guide the user is taken to a success page after the payment is successful. What I want to do upon a successful payment is collect the user's email, create a randomized password, and then email that password to the user. I've learned how to grab information from the session id using this page (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page). What I'm concerned about is that a user might go to the success page, get an account, and bypass the required payment.

My idea to solve that is to get the session info using this line:

> session = stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(request.args.get('session_id'))

and then before doing anything else check if it's none. If it's none, it will display an error page, if it is not none then it will create an account for the user. Would that work? Or would people just be able to change the session_id in the url until they find a number that is a valid session?

If that doesn't work, all I really want to do is upon successful payment create an account for the user using their email and a randomized password. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Generally the flow is:

1. Customer is redirected to Checkout
2. Customer pays
3. Checkout redirects customer back to your `success_url`
4. You fetch the Checkout Session using the ID in the URL to confirm a valid payment

For #4 you can do various things to make sure people can't guess a Checkout Session ID (which would be unlikely due to their length and complexity).  I suggest checking to see if the successful payment happened within a certain timeframe, like the past hour or past day, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much! For q4, is there an industry standard? I imagine an hour is a pretty reasonable amount of time, but if there's a standard way to confirm the purchase, I'll use that.

Comment: There's no industry standard I'm aware of, as the specifics would depend on the business needs, use case, risk model, payment methods used, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks. (Here are some extra characters to meet the comment requirement)